# Uncaught TypeError: aniversario.split is not a function

Tags: javascript, webforms

Estou com esta função em javascript que calcula a idade:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  function calcularIdade(aniversario) {
    var nascimento = aniversario.split("/");
    var dataNascimento = new Date(parseInt(nascimento[2], 10),
      parseInt(nascimento[1], 10) - 1,
      parseInt(nascimento[0], 10));

    var diferenca = Date.now() - dataNascimento.getTime();
    var idade = new Date(diferenca);

    return Math.abs(idade.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
  }
</script>
```

Esta é a linha onde realizo o cálculo, lembrando que a máscara deste campo é "29/11/2017"

```
<input type="text" id="nascimento" onkeypress="mascara(this,mdata)" maxlength="10" name="nascimento" onblur="calcularIdade(this)" runat="server" class="form-control" />
```

Quando estou digitando a data, ele não está informando a idade, fui verificar e está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: aniversario.split is not a function
>       at calcularIdade (Pessoas.aspx?id=2:444)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onblur

Me retorna erro nesta linha:

```
var nascimento = aniversario.split("/");
```

Já tentei de várias formas, verifiquei o valor, tá saindo no formato dd/mm/yyyy

Atualizando:
Função que utilizo para colocar máscara no campo:

```js
function mascara(o, f) {
  v_obj = o
  v_fun = f
  setTimeout("execmascara()", 1)
}

function execmascara() {
  v_obj.value = v_fun(v_obj.value)
}

function mdata(v) { // máscara para o user digitar sempre dd/mm/aaaa
  v = v.replace(/\D/g, ""); //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
  v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1/$2");
  v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1/$2");

  v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, "$1$2");
  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou colocar `this.value` no `onblur`, assim:

```
onblur="calcularIdade(this.value)"
```

Isso irá enviar à função o valor do campo, e não o elemento em si, causando o erro no `split`.

Trocar o `onkeypress` por `onkeyup` para poder retornar o `length` do campo corretamente ao ser digitado.

Adicionei um `if` na função `mascara()` que irá chamar a função que calcula a idade assim que o campo tiver 10 caracteres.

```js
function mascara(o, f) {
  v_obj = o
  v_fun = f
  setTimeout("execmascara()", 1)
  
  // linhas adicionadas
  if(v_obj.value.length == 10){
     calcularIdade(v_obj.value);
  }
}

function execmascara() {
  v_obj.value = v_fun(v_obj.value)
}

function mdata(v) { // máscara para o user digitar sempre dd/mm/aaaa
  v = v.replace(/\D/g, ""); //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
  v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1/$2");
  v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1/$2");

  v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, "$1$2");
  return v;
}


function calcularIdade(aniversario) {
    var nascimento = aniversario.split("/");
    var dataNascimento = new Date(parseInt(nascimento[2], 10),
      parseInt(nascimento[1], 10) - 1,
      parseInt(nascimento[0], 10));

    var diferenca = Date.now() - dataNascimento.getTime();
    var idade = new Date(diferenca);

    return console.log(Math.abs(idade.getUTCFullYear() - 1970));
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nascimento" onkeyup="mascara(this,mdata)" maxlength="10" name="nascimento" onblur="calcularIdade(this.value)" runat="server" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Eu preciso que na hora que o usuário digite a data, calcule a idade, coloquei da forma que você me informou, não ocorre erro, porém ele também não calcula a data.

Comment: @marianac_costa poste o código da máscara, ela que está controlando o keypress.

Comment: Atualizei com o código da máscara. Obrigado.

Comment: @marianac_costa atualizei a resposta... veja se esse onblur é necessário mesmo. Talvez não precise dele.

Comment: @marianac_costa e aí, funcionou?

Comment: Porque essa linha `v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1/$2");` está repetida?

Comment: Isso é da programação dele, eu nem havia notado.

Comment: @ÐvÐ desculpe a demora, fiz os testes e funcionou corretamente, apenas alterei para aparecer a idade no TextBox txtidade, e deu certo. Obrigado.